# Writing text output from map function hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Input :

a,b,c,d,e

q,w,34,r,e

1,2,3,4,e

In mapper, I would grab all the values of the last field, and I want to emit (e,(a,b,c,d)) i.e. it emits (key, (rest of the fields from the line)).

Help appreciated.

Current code:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
   private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString(); // reads the input line by line   
        String[] attr = line.split(","); // extract each attribute values from the csv record
         context.write(attr[argno-1],line); // gives error seems to like only integer? how to override this?
        }
    }
 } 
 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // further process , loads the chunk into 2d arraylist object for processing
    }
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String line; 
    String arguements[];
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        // compute the total number of attributes in the file
    FileReader infile = new FileReader(args[0]);
    BufferedReader bufread = new BufferedReader(infile);
    line = bufread.readLine();
    arguements = line.split(","); // split the fields separated by comma
    conf.setInt("argno", arguements.length); // saving that attribute value 
    Job job = new Job(conf, "nb");
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class); /* The method setMapperClass(Class<? extends Mapper>) in the type Job is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Map>) */
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }`
```

Please note the errors (see comments) I get face.

Comment: So you want it to output <e, {a,b,c,d,e; q,w,34,r,e; 1,2,3,4,e}>?

Comment: Yes. This would be the output from each mapper. So basically the (key,value) is nothing but (Text,Text). Plus I would want to filter them using a combiner based on the key before the reducer gets hold of it. This is because, I want a reduce function to run for each "key" and I don't want more than one reducer working on the same "key.

Comment: @Brad Semrad Sorry, I made a mistake. Please see my above updated post for the correct requirement. Sorry for the mix-up / confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is simple. First parse your string to get the key and pass the rest of the line as the value. Then use the identity reducer which will combine all the same key values as list together as your output. It should be in the same format.

So your map function will output:

e, (a,b,c,d,e)

e, (q,w,34,r,e)

e, (1,2,3,4,e)

Then after the identity reduce it should output:

e, {a,b,c,d,e; q,w,34,r,e; 1,2,3,4,e}

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
   private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString(); // reads the input line by line   
        String[] attr = line.split(","); // extract each attribute values from the csv record
         context.write(attr[argno-1],line); // gives error seems to like only integer? how to override this?
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String line; 
        String arguements[];
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        // compute the total number of attributes in the file
        FileReader infile = new FileReader(args[0]);
        BufferedReader bufread = new BufferedReader(infile);
        line = bufread.readLine();
        arguements = line.split(","); // split the fields separated by comma
        conf.setInt("argno", arguements.length); // saving that attribute value 
        Job job = new Job(conf, "nb");
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class); 
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }
```

Comment: @stholy I do not see any code posted. Please place it in your original post.

Comment: I was thinking that once the map function is complete, the shuffle would sort and then pass on the map output to reducer. The reducer is suppose to do some other function.

Comment: Not sure if it causes it but make your Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>, you still have IntWriteable

Comment: @stholy Don't forget that the reduce might happen multiple times and not just once.

Comment: @bradCould you please post the right code to allow the map function to write (Key (Text),rest of the columns(Text)) as output?

Comment: @stholy Yes that should do it

Comment: @bradI can't see your changes.

Comment: @stholy that should do it. If it doesn't work, I have an easy simple fix, assuming I didn't mess up the configuration

Answer (score -5):

Found alternate logic. Implemented , tested and verified.